# Reverse vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a list of descriptions and I want to add a code column as shown below. The descriptions in the list are neither unique nor sorted.

I have an index table with substrings and the codes in separate columns. vlookup doesn't seem to work.

List:

```
Description     Code
=============== =====
Horse shoes     Horse
Saddle cloth    Horse
Saddlery grease Horse
Shearing board  Wool
Shearer         Wool
Saddle cloth    Horse
Shearer         Wool
```

Index:

```
Substring Code
========= ====
Horse     Horse
Saddle    Horse
Shear     Wool
```

Comment: Hi, welcome.  It isn't clear from your question what you are after.  Could you [edit] and see if you can make it clearer?

Comment: vlookup only works when the item you are checking is in the column to the far left of your data table.
I suggest you move the "Code" coloum to the left of the "Substring" and "Description" coloums.

Answer (score 2):

The formula you need:

`=INDEX($E$1:$E$4,MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$4,A2)*ROW($D$2:$D$4),"")))`

This is an array formula, you need to enter it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

Comment: OK, got it - EXCELLENT!!! Search for 'excel CSE'. A bit tricky to enter and edit.

Comment: There are a few [disadvantages of using array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7), especially since I need to constantly change the Description array. Can this be put in a macro?

Comment: You can convert your description range to a table (insert - table), and use table references in the formulas (e.g table1.substring; even will automatically use this type when you direct part of a table). This way your formula will be updated when you as new rows to the description.

Comment: Complicated. Let me explain this formula: The index looks up the maximum value from the search of the array; the search of text in text searched returns 1 if found otherwise 0 which is multiplied by the last row searched then replaced by null if an error occurs; the search result is multiplied by the last row searched but blanked if it is an error. How is the formula written if the index range is named 'table1.substring' and the Substring is changed from 'Saddle' to 'addle'?

Comment: Note that the search function should look for any occurrence of substring in string but this example must find the substring at the start of the string. I don't know why.